# Log Cat is not working properly in eclipse , windows

Tags: java, android, eclipse, windows

I am developing an application which needs to save data during the orientation change.

for referencing the flow of oncreate,onstart,onsavedinstance,onrestoreinstance etc for different option in my app i need log cat very much.so i created `log.d(TAG,"This is onCreate() method");` and vice versa for all different methods in log cat i am getting all the info when it got created and when it got destroyed.
But double clicking the statement is not taking me to the statement in activity class. I want my logcat to take me to particular place if i click on statements in logcat or errors.I used to have this option in ubuntu dont know why i cant do it now.

Any type of help is appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

not all statements will take you to the code but only statements which makes use of line number will take you to the code ( exception if you are using jar eclipse can not show you that code when you double click the logcat)

Comment: do i have any options or tweaks to make to let this happen

Answer (score 0):

At last i found an answer myself. 
In search type devices and open it.
and select the device you want log cat information , that will be loaded instantly